# ZBar SDK iOS: Remove cancel button in scanner view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, zbar-sdk

Is there a way to remove the cancel button in the initial scan view?  I have my App set to go immediately to scanner, so the cancel is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  While setting showZBarControls = NO removes the entire bar, I needed something that would just remove the cancel button.  The best way to do this was to remove the ZbarControls and create a new toolbar and overlay it.

Comment: It might be easier for you to access the `UIToolbar`'s properties, and then setting the cancel button to nil.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using version 1.2 of the SDK and you are also using the ZBarReaderViewController, you could set the property showsZBarControls = NO;

That will remove the cancel and information button.