# how to change default cancel,info button in zbar sdk in iphone

Tags: iphone, zbar-sdk

When we press on button to scan QR code there is default cancel,info button.

I require another button that on flash.So how can i change in zbaerviewcontroller to customize it.

Answer (score 2):

While setting `showZBarControls = NO` removes the entire bar, I needed something that would just remove the cancel button. The best way to do this was to remove the **ZbarControls** and create a new toolbar and overlay it.

Hope it help to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the cancel button by setting the property `showsZBarControls = NO;`

Refer the following links,

[How to hide info button in ZBar Bar Code Reader for iOS6.0 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353491/how-to-hide-info-button-in-zbar-bar-code-reader-for-ios6-0-and-above)

[ZBar SDK iOS: Remove cancel button in scanner view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205207/zbar-sdk-ios-remove-cancel-button-in-scanner-view)